# Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in

Tags: php, oracle11g

I want use simple oracle insert statement with php from variable data on oracle database, but I am getting error on browser:

> oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

I am following few answer but not getting answer work for me. Here is my code:

```
include("conn.php");
            $THR_ATTENDANCERAW_ID = 'AAANttAAMAAANG1ABF';
            $AD_CLIENT_ID = '8D8C2A846B2545128823CC7611C9EF80';
            $AD_ORG_ID = 'BB7935DD9F9F46B8A3CEBFB8CA73929B';
            $ISACTIVE = 'Y';
            $CREATED = '03/21/2018 10:20:12';
            $CREATEDBY = '0';
            $UPDATED = '03/21/2018 10:20:12';
            $UPDATEDBY = '0';
            $CHECKTIME = '03/21/2018 10:20:12';
            $USERNO = '10842803';
            $DOCUMENTNO = '0010842803';
            $ISMANUAL = 'N';
            $DEVICENO = '2';
            $ATTENDANCETYPE = '0';
            $ERROR_CODE = '0';
            $PRODUCTNAME = 'NULL';
            $SERIAL_NUMBER = 'NULL';
            $ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 'NULL';
            $NAME = 'NULL';
            $S_TIME = 'NULL';
            $MACHINE = 'NULL';
            $VERIFY_MODE = 'NULL';




            $sql1 = "
            INSERT INTO THR_ATTENDANCERAW (THR_ATTENDANCERAW_ID, AD_CLIENT_ID, AD_ORG_ID, ISACTIVE, CREATED, 
                        CREATEDBY, UPDATED, UPDATEDBY, CHECKTIME, USERNO, 
                        DOCUMENTNO, ISMANUAL, DEVICENO, ATTENDANCETYPE, ERROR_CODE, 
                        PRODUCTNAME, SERIAL_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NAME, S_TIME, 
                        MACHINE, VERIFY_MODE) 
            VALUES (
                'AAANttAAMAAANG1ABF, :AD_CLIENT_ID, :AD_ORG_ID, :ISACTIVE, :CREATED, :CREATEDBY, :UPDATED, :UPDATEDBY, :CHECKTIME, :USERNO, :DOCUMENTNO, :ISMANUAL, :DEVICENO, :ATTENDANCETYPE, :ERROR_CODE, :PRODUCTNAME, :SERIAL_NUMBER, :ACCOUNT_NUMBER, :NAME, :S_TIME, :MACHINE, :VERIFY_MODE')" ;
            //echo $sql1;
       $compiled1 = oci_parse($conn, $sql1);

            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':THR_ATTENDANCERAW_ID', $THR_ATTENDANCERAW_ID);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':AD_CLIENT_ID', $AD_CLIENT_ID);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':AD_ORG_ID', $AD_ORG_ID);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':ISACTIVE', $ISACTIVE);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':CREATED', $CREATED);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':CREATEDBY', $CREATEDBY);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':UPDATED', $UPDATED);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':UPDATEDBY', $UPDATEDBY);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':CHECKTIME', $CHECKTIME);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':USERNO', $USERNO);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':DOCUMENTNO', $DOCUMENTNO);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':ISMANUAL', $ISMANUAL);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':DEVICENO', $DEVICENO);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':ATTENDANCETYPE', $ATTENDANCETYPE);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':ERROR_CODE', $ERROR_CODE);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':PRODUCTNAME', $PRODUCTNAME);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':SERIAL_NUMBER', $SERIAL_NUMBER);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':ACCOUNT_NUMBER', $ACCOUNT_NUMBER);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':NAME', $NAME);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':S_TIME', $S_TIME);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':MACHINE', $MACHINE);
            oci_bind_by_name($compiled1, ':VERIFY_MODE', $VERIFY_MODE);



        oci_execute($compiled1); 

        ?>
```

error shown as :

```
Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 42

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 43

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 44

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 45

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 46

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 47

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 48

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 49

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 50

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 51

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 52

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 53

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 54

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 55

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 56

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 57

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 58

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 59

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 60

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 61

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 62

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 63

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00947: not enough values in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib\insert.php on line 67
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use PHP.

The last line in your error stack says

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00947: not enough values

If you look at the $sql1, which says something like this:

```
INSERT INTO THR_ATTENDANCERAW 
  (THR_ATTENDANCERAW_ID, 
   AD_CLIENT_ID, 
   <snip>
   VERIFY_MODE)
 VALUES 
   ('AAANttAAMAAANG1ABF, :AD_CLIENT_ID, <snip>, :VERIFY_MODE')
    ^                                                       ^
    here                                                    here
```

See those single quotes in the last line? In Oracle, they mean that you're inserting a **string** (that's everything you see between those single quotes).

I presume that Oracle thinks that there are 22 columns to be populated with some values, and you are inserting only one - a *long* string, into the first column (THR_ATTENDANCERAW_ID).

So, as the first value really looks like a string, enclose only that value into single quotes, i.e. `'AAANttAAMAAANG1ABF'`, and leave the rest intact (of course, remove the ending single quote).

Comment: I get it,Thanks for helps